# Need help remembering this sci-fi comedy show from 90s

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

I only remember bits and pieces. It seemed like Star Trek with comedy elements. I think it takes place on a ship in space. There is a group and I think there might have been one black dude among the crew.

I remember that in one episode, they crash or something on maybe another planet. They have no food and somehow they end up eating one of the crews without them knowing that it was human flesh they were eating and not a chicken or something.

Does anyone know what show I'm talking about?

Comment: Pretty sure you're thinking of *Red Dwarf*, but since I can't place that specific episode, I can't say for certain.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It sounds like you're referring to the [Red Dwarf](http://www.reddwarf.co.uk/home/index.cfm) episode "[Tikka to Ride](http://www.planetsmeg.com/cgi-bin/pagegen.pl?tikka)"

> **CAT :** *Chicken's good.*
>
> **LISTER :** *Yeah, really good.*
>
> **KRYTEN :** *That's not chicken, sir.*
>
> **CAT :** *Oh, what is it?*
>
> **KRYTEN :** *It's that man we found*.

[image: Chicken Cannibal Red Dwarf]

You can watch the full episode [here](http://vimeo.com/63895915)

Comment: Hahha, yes that's it!!!!

Answer (score 15):

That sounds like the British TV series [*Red Dwarf*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Dwarf). There are several episodes where they crash on planets, moons, asteroids, etc., and there were both [mixed-race](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craig_Charles) and [black](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_John-Jules) cast members (although the latter was actually playing a super-evolved humanoid [cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Red_Dwarf%29)).

I believe the specific episode you're thinking of is ["Tikka to Ride"](http://www.planetsmeg.com/cgi-bin/pagegen.pl?tikka), season 7 episode 1.

Comment: That's exactly the show I was looking for.